# Cannot use nomencl package, makeindex doesn't works with my preamble

Tags: indexing, acronyms, sorting, nomenclature, preamble

Time ago I had an issue with Tikz and mathpazo, building my preamble as a post here recommended. In that way my document could compile once again and well, so on the project grew. So my preamble now is huge:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[10pt,final,notitlepage,openbib]{book} % (fold)
\usepackage[LGRx,TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx} 
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,spanish,activeacute,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo} 
%\usepackage{palatino,eulervm,eufrak}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{quotchap}
%\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,empheq,bm}

%%%%%%%% Paquetes complementarios
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{epigraph}
%\usepackage{multicolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\poise{P}
\DeclareSIUnit\stokes{St}
%\DeclareSIUnit\radian{rad}
\DeclareSIUnit\dyna{dyn}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[spanish,intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=true,           % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    %pdfstartview={FitH},   % fits the width of the page to the window
   pdftitle={Modelado y Simulación de diferentes grados de estenosis en arterias empleando elementos finitos},    % title
    pdfauthor={Víctor Daniel Vela Cuevas},     % author
    pdfsubject={Hemodinámica},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Victor Daniel Vela Cuevas},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Listopad}, % producer of the document
    %pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=false,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=red,          % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor)
    citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=cyan           % color of external links
}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
%\usepackage{layout}
%\usepackage{theorem}

%%%%%%% Glosas 

%\usepackage{glossaries}
%\makeglossaries

%%%%% Acronimos

\usepackage{acronym}
\acrodef{LBD}{Lipoproteinas de baja densidad}
\acrodef{VOP}{Velocidad de onda de pulso}
%\acrodef{FP}{Falsos Positivos}
%%%%%%% Citas múltiples

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mref}{m}{\quinn_mref:n {#1}}
\seq_new:N \l_quinn_mref_seq
\cs_new:Npn \quinn_mref:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_quinn_mref_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_quinn_mref_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  ( % print the left parenthesis
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_quinn_mref_seq
    { \ref{##1},\nobreakspace } % print the first references
  \exp_args:NV \ref \l_tmpa_tl % print the last or only one
  ) % print the right parenthesis
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%%%%%%% Page Style
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{ %
\fancyhf{} % remove everything
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\makeatletter
  \def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
  \vspace*{\fill}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Apéndices}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Apéndices}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Apéndices}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\singlespacing
\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing

%%%%%%% Graficos
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure,etex,tikz,pgfplots}
\graphicspath{{./imagen/}}
%\definecolor{burntorange}{cmyk}{0,0.51,1,0}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\newcommand{\Fin}{node[xshift=-1.5ex,rotate=10]{F}
                  node[rotate=170]{i}
                  node[xshift=1.5ex,rotate=45]{n}}

 %%%%%%% Ultimos ajustes
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,spanish,textsize=footnotesize]{todonotes}

\usepackage[stable,bottom]{footmisc}
\raggedbottom
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=1000
\setlength{\parskip}{3pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\newcommand{\greek}[1]{{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sen}{sen}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diverg}{div}
\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rot}{rot}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{traza}

\newtheorem{define}{Definición}[chapter]
% Preamble (end)
```

This is the preamble for my thesis, it works fine, but don't let me build a nomenclature list with the package nomencl. In fact inside the document I use the tag `\include{}` for attach each chapter, so, below that logic, I tried to create a chapter for nomenclature list:

```
\nomenclature[01]{$D$}{Diámetro del tubo o arteria}
\nomenclature[02]{$E$}{Módulo de Young}
\nomenclature[03]{$f$}{Frecuencia}
\nomenclature[04]{$g$}{Aceleración gravitacional}
\nomenclature[05]{$L$}{Longitud del tubo o vaso}
\nomenclature[06]{$M_{10}^{\prime}$}{Amplitud de una función especial que surge de la teoría de Womersley}
\nomenclature[11]{$Re$}{Numero de Reynolds}
%etc

\printnomenclature
```

But it didn't work. I made another proof with a smaller preamble from an ancient version of the thesis, and I found that I must put my nomenclature list directly inside the master document instead a document apart. So then, inside that another document, the nomenclature list appeared. Trying to do the same inside my master document with the preamble above, again doesn't works.

As the package document suggest, I use in a terminal the instructions: `makeindex filename.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o filename.nls` of course, before I use the `cd` command for choose the right path of my document and I compile it before with pdflatex, later, I run the makeindex with the syntax above, but is when I get this message error:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2013] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist...done (10 attributes redefined, 3 ignored).
Scanning input file Debugger.nlo...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in Debugger.nls.
Transcript written in Debugger.ilg.
```

My hypothesis is that there is something wrong inside my preamble, something that don't let me compile it right. I hope someone here can help me, or suggest a solution. I know my preamble is a little messy, so I accept suggestions.

Finally, I hope that this question is valid and will not  be invalidated by being related to a previous, yet I dared raise it as a new question instead of from a previous thread because I think that although the package Nomencl has several threads alluding it, none fully meets my doubt.

Regards.

Comment: You call the nomencl package twice. I wouldn't be surprised if this causes your problems. In the preamble it says: `\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[spanish,intoc]{nomencl}`. Comment out the first and then see if it works.

Comment: Well, sorry, I wrote the `nomencl` package twice, but in fact I have in my preamble only once. I Have the idea of call the nomencl before the makeidx package, but was not a good idea, now it's worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reduced your given code and made it compilable.

On my system (MIKTeX 2.9, Windows 7) I get **no error**, **no warning** with the following code, based on yours:

```
% !!!!!!!! don't forget:    makeindex filename.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o filename.nls
\listfiles
\documentclass[10pt,final,notitlepage,openbib]{book} % (fold)
\usepackage[LGRx,TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage[spanish,intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%%%% Acronimos
\usepackage{acronym}
\acrodef{LBD}{Lipoproteinas de baja densidad}
\acrodef{VOP}{Velocidad de onda de pulso}
%\acrodef{FP}{Falsos Positivos}

\begin{document}
test
\nomenclature[01]{$D$}{Diámetro del tubo o arteria}
\nomenclature[02]{$E$}{Módulo de Young}
\nomenclature[03]{$f$}{Frecuencia}
\nomenclature[04]{$g$}{Aceleración gravitacional}
\nomenclature[05]{$L$}{Longitud del tubo o vaso}
\nomenclature[06]{$M_{10}^{\prime}$}{Amplitud de una función especial que surge de la teoría de Womersley}
\nomenclature[11]{$Re$}{Numero de Reynolds}
%etc
test 2

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Please copy my MWE to your computer and compile it three times, don't forget `makeindex`.  What is the result on your system? No errors? Look where are the differences to your code. Errors? Which distribution do you use, perhaps outdated?

Comment: Oh my God!!!  This is great, I was busy with the experimental part of the thesis so I had not chance for reduce my own code and to give us a minimal functional example, and now you did it. \o/ 

Thans a lot for your helping, I'll try it tomorrow and hope it works well, I will review carefully changes and improvements.

Comment: Thanks again, I used your code and with the nomenclature it works, I have no error to compile. I use both TeXLive 2013 (is not outdated) and MikTeX 2.9 (not outdated also). For compile your MWE I did it with TeXLive and all works fine. But not for my chapters and all the other packages I have, so I must find yet how to make work all togheter.

Comment: Thanks for writing the comment `% !!!!!!!! don't forget:`. I was using another `ist` file.

Comment: @Sigur You are welcome!